# body HTML height 100%

Tags: jquery, html, height

When I try to set html,body to 100% height, all the jquery scripts which rely on scroll position stop working.
Why is this?
http://creativelycoded.com/demos/Astonish/one-page/index.html

Here is my site. If you use inspect element and add the 100% heights you will see what I mean.

I need the 100% heights to get background-size: cover to work properly on iPhone and iPad. Right now the background images scale to the entire height of the document. But when I add 100% height to html and body they scale properly but my scripts screw up.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

you can't have html or body with height:100% and use scripts based on scroll positions. scrollTop() no longer works

try `html, body{ height:100vh; }`

This is using the new vh unit in CSS3 which means 100% of the viewport height. It works in modern browsers.

Support table: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

I believe setting height to 100% means there will be no scroll bar, and so no scroll position.

If you set css:

```
html{ overflow-y: scroll; }
```

it might fix it.

Answer (score -1):

add style in your html code like `style="height:100%"`